# How to architect a single page, API-consuming app using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, architecture, routes

I need to build a single-page JavaScript web app that, on regular intervals, pulls data from a couple of public and maybe a few private APIs, and present & refresh the data in different tables. I could build it purely as front-end code with jQuery and just use AJAX calls, but to keep the keys and everything for the APIs private, I need the logic that retrieves the API data to live in backend code (on the same server).

I'm new to building this kind of application, and wondering how to achieve this with NodeJS. After searching and looking at some tutorials, the only way I can wrap my head around it so far is to have an index.html that displays the view with the empty tables, then on a setInterval, have a local JavaScript function do an AJAX call to a NodeJS (Express) route that handles all the API stuff and returns a JSON object in the response. On success, the local JavaScript can write the results to the html for the various tables/divs.

That sounds OK to me, but since all of this will have to live on the same server, it seems really weird to have a front-end script do manual calls to that same server via a URL/route.

What am I conceptually missing? Do I need to employ a master Express layout and use partials for the divs/tables and have the Node backend process the front-end that way? Or should I stick to building .html and .js outside of Express and maybe use something like Angular to create a more intuitive front-end piece? I'm not sure how either of these scenarios would be put together, I'm just feeling around for a better approach.

Comment: The way I would approach this is with an Angular app. Exactly as you state you would have an API that is built on nodeJS (a bunch of defined routes that grab data and return JSON), and then your front-end angular app. Correct, every set interval your app would call the endpoints you defined in your API, and then update $scope variables based on the JSON response. Your HTML would actually be updated in real time automatically (since that's how angular works with binding models and templates/partials). I would look into angular - sounds like a perfect solution!

Comment: Also, once you understand how the binding of angular works, you will never want to write jQuery html() append() or any of those DOM manipulation functions again.

Comment: I thought I was taking a stab, but nice to know I'm on the right track. I'll explore the Angular path. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Yikes. I gotta say, I'm a little less thrilled about taking on Angular with the recently announced changes that will come with version 2.0. Maybe I'll keep the same architecture, but look at a comparable framework. Or maybe stick with jQuery doing the AJAX calls and use a library to put binded data into an HTML template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as Community Wiki answer, as this got answered in comments:

> The way I would approach this is with an Angular app. Exactly as you state you would have an API that is built on nodeJS (a bunch of defined routes that grab data and return JSON), and then your front-end angular app. Correct, every set interval your app would call the endpoints you defined in your API, and then update $scope variables based on the JSON response. Your HTML would actually be updated in real time automatically (since that's how angular works with binding models and templates/partials). I would look into angular - sounds like a perfect solution!
>
> Also, once you understand how the binding of angular works, you will never want to write jQuery html() append() or any of those DOM manipulation functions again.

Comment: @Alex, I have posted your suggestions from comments into answer by Community Wiki. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments